# R data.table LEFT JOIN not working properly

Tags: r, data.table

So I am trying to do a LEFT join on two `data.table`s in R. Perhaps my understanding is wrong, but I thought that in a left join was supposed to fill non-matching rows with nulls or something, but in this case, I actually lose rows from my LEFT JOIN. Why?

```
> nrow(aaa)
[1] 30070
> ccc <- merge(aaa, bbb, all.X = TRUE)
> nrow(ccc)
[1] 23358
```

Comment: Isn't it `all.x` not `all.X`?

Comment: @DavidHeckmann Yeah, I'm honestly not sure; it could just be a typo in the Q by the OP. Sort of would expect an "unused argument" error.

Comment: ok, I tried `all.x`, and it worked as expected, thanks

Comment: There's no error because `merge` has a `...` argument which will accept and silently ignore any unused arguments.

Answer (score 2):

```
ccc <- merge(aaa, bbb, all.x = TRUE)
```

@joran is correct